# How do you secure a nozzle on your pastry bag?

Tags: pastry, piping

Ok, so I remade my eclair filling with a 1:1 butter to condensed milk ratio. It was a pain, but it seems I did it! The thing is I don't want my cooking to be a pain, I want it to be enjoyable. The piping certainly wasn't. The filling, even though it was apparently thick enough, still partially leaked over the nozzle and not through the opening. I had to manually push it against the bag which, given everything else I had to simultaneously do, took active participation of every finger I had on my hands. I can't just duct-tape it to the bag, can I? That particular nozzle was purchased separately from the bag

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPD: @rumtscho Golly, I thought it was just a weird-looking nozzle! But I need a wider connector for that needle-like nozzle I bought separately

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your buttercream still looks not stiff enough, although probably OK for eclairs. For next time, you may want to check if you are using some unusual kind of condensed milk (the right one is quite viscous when it comes out of the can, a bit like noncrystalized honey), and if you are beating the butter well enough before adding the milk (try doing at least 6 min by a timer, more if you have an off-brand or ancient mixer).

Comment: @rumtscho what should the butter look like? How do I know it's whipped enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never run into such trouble. Are you trying to keep the tip on the outside?

For work with the same tip, as you have in eclairs, it goes inside the bag. You start by cutting a hole in the bag that is smaller than the tip's upper diameter, then slide it in. Then you fill the bag, knead it, and pipe. If the tip slides out, the hole was too large, use another bag.

If you want to change tips on the same bag, you have to use a special holding ring. There is a connector that goes inside the piping bag, the tip gets slipped onto the connector, and there is a ring with screw threads that comes from the outside and secures the tip to the connector. These connector-ring-sets tend to come with sets of tips, or sometimes with non-disposable bags, but you can probably also get them solo.

Oh, and there is no rule saying you can't duct tape in the kitchen (your home kitchen, at least). You'll have to do it before it comes in contact with the greasy filling, though. And cleaning your tools afterwards might be difficult.

Comment: BTW I've given up on the greaseproof paper piping bags you can buy or make, and buy plastic ones. Whether bought or home made the paper piping bags tend to either split or tear at the nozzle with stiff contents. The one in the photo looks like my paper ones.

Comment: @ChrisH I think it’s a reusable one - I think see a seam at the top?

Comment: Yes, it's reusable. I don't like producing more waste than I can

Comment: @Stephie it looked just like a crease on a small screen (even on desktop I couldn't be sure). (@ Sergey) I don't do much piping, and I'd waste a lot of hot water washing up a reusable one - it would need handwashing as the dishwasher wouldn't do a very good job, but everything goes in the dishwasher which is many times more efficient.  I wash up by hand less than once a month.

Comment: I have a thingy which looks like the syringes doctors use, only much bigger. It came with a set of nozzles to screw on, and is machine washable. I will never use a bag again.

Comment: @RedSonja they're nice, and what I'd get again if I did more piping.  My last one wasn't infinitely dishwasher safe, and eventually got cracks in it (it was probably acrylic).